# Bootstrap col-md-3 arranging

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to design this footer on a web page, and I've set that my containers for text and social buttons to be col-md-3. So far so good, but I'd like them to arrange themselves in 3 to 2 lines, when I'm resizing the window, it snaps from 4 columns, to 3 columns, and then directly to 1 column

```
<footer class="container-fluid container-footer">
```

FOOTER</span>-->

```
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
        <span> DARKWOOD </span>
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
        <span> PRODUCTS </span>
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <span> ABOUT</span>
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 social-hub">
        <span> SOCIAL</span>
        <div class="row-fluid for-social">
            <a href="#"><div class="col-xs-3 social" id="facebook"></div></a>
            <a href="#"><div class="col-xs-3 social" id="google-plus"></div></a>
            <a href="#"><div class="col-xs-3 social" id="twitter"></div></a>
            <a href="#"><div class="col-xs-3 social" id="tumblr"></div></a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="col-md-12" id="copyright"></div>
```

All the code is over here:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x0cfoz88/)

Also, pics:

Initally:[image: Initial]

Intermediate:
[image]

Last:[image]

So, as you can see, there's enough space for at least 2 of the categories is the final image.

//EDIT//
Can you guys think about anything to solve this stuff?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to add additional 'col' classes to describe the behaviour you want. For example, if you want 2x2 on small screens, you need to do something like this:

```
<footer class="container-fluid container-footer">
    <div class="row-fluid ">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
            <span> DARKWOOD </span>

            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Lorem Ipsum</p>
            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Lorem Ipsum</p>
            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Lorem Ipsum</p>
            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Lorem Ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
            <span> PRODUCTS </span>

            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Lorem Ipsum</p>
            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Lorem Ipsum</p>
            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Lorem Ipsum</p>
            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Lorem Ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
            <span> ABOUT</span>

            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Lorem Ipsum</p>
            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Lorem Ipsum</p>
            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Lorem Ipsum</p>
            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Lorem Ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 social-hub col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
            <span> SOCIAL</span>

            <div class="row-fluid for-social">
                <a href="#"><div class="col-xs-3 social" id="facebook"></div></a>
                <a href="#"><div class="col-xs-3 social" id="google-plus"></div></a>
                <a href="#"><div class="col-xs-3 social" id="twitter"></div></a>
                <a href="#"><div class="col-xs-3 social" id="tumblr"></div></a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" id="copyright"></div>
</footer>
```

Bear in mind that a 'row' is 12 'units' wide and that anything at the 'size' (eg. md, sm etc) that is over 12 will be wrapped.  So above, by setting the div widths to 6 (col-sm-4 + col-sm-offset-2), they will wrap in pairs until the extra small size takes over.

So, col-md-3 means 3/12s the width of the container at medium size.

Also keep in mind that these classes apply upwards only (eg. col-md-3 will work at medium and large, but not small or extra small).

Comment: It's close to what I want, but my copyright text snaps upwards, or on the roght of the divs when I resize, can you think of anything to stop that, I want it to stay of the bottom of the page at all times.

Comment: Nevermind, I managed :) Thanks for the solution, I didn't know you could actually insert multiple class descriptors so that the divs will comport differently.

Comment: One more thing, could you tell me if you know how to resolve the thing I posted in the last image?

Comment: I see two problems: 1) you need to put the col-xs class in the immediate child of the container (so on the <a> instead of the <div>) and 2) if you want to wrap it into a square, you need to use 6 instead of 3.  Note: I'm not sure how wise it is to apply the grid classes to anchor tags.